# Webservice Php sem Lib

Tags: php, web-service

Opa, dei uma olhada no Stack atrás de uma questão simples, porém que está me deixando confuso.
Conhecer o conceito de Webservice é relativamente fácil, porém a prática é o foco desta questão. Vi algumas outras perguntas por aqui, mas que não foram respondidas devido a como a pergunta foi colocada, então pretendo especificar, exemplificar o melhor possível para que possam me ajudar.

É fácil encontrar Libs para se desenvolver um Webservice, a questão é, conceitualmente posso criar um Webservice sem nenhuma Lib? Por exemplo, receber o dado via Post, ou Get, manipula-lo e retornar uma resposta em Json, ou XML para uma aplicação desenvolvida em uma plataforma diferente? Mantendo interoperabilidade e outras características de um webservice...

Como Gambiarra já fiz isso:

```
<?php
    include 'servidor.php';

    $resposta=array();

    if(isset($_GET['comando'])){
        $comando=$_GET['comando'];
        switch($comando){
            case "Inserir":
                if(isset($_GET['nome']) && isset($_GET['ra'])){
                    $r=inserirContato($_GET['nome'] , $_GET['ra']);
                        if($r){
                            $resposta['codigo']=1;
                            $resposta['mensagem']="Sucesso ao inserir!";
                        }else{
                            $resposta['codigo']=0;
                            $resposta['mensagem']="Erro ao inserir!";
                        }
                }else{
                    $resposta['codigo']=0;
                    $resposta['mensagem']="Campos ausentes!";
                }
        break;
```

Mas também já fiz isso:

```
<?php
    include 'conexao.class.php';
    include 'lib/nusoap.php'; // BAIXADO DA INTERNET

    $server = new nusoap_server;
    $server->configureWSDL('agenda','urn:agenda');
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace='urn:agenda';


    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        'Contato',
        'complexType',
        'struct',
        'all',
        '',
        array(
            'id'=>array('name'=>'id','type'=>'xsd:int'),
            'nome'=>array('name'=>'nome','type'=>'xsd:string'),
            'telefone'=>
            array('name'=>'telefone','type'=>'xsd:string')
        )
    );

    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
        'ArrayString',
        'complexType',
        'array',
        '',
        'SOAP-ENC:Array',
        array(),
        array(
            array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
            'wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')
        ),
        'xsd:string'
    );

    $server->register(
        'procurarContato',
        array('id'=>'xsd:int'),
        array('return'=>'tns:Contato'),
        'urn:agenda',
        'urn:agenda#procurarContato',
        'rpc',
        'encoded',
        'Procurar contato'
    );

    function procurarContato($id){
        $con = new conexao();
        if($con->connect()){
            $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contato where id='$id'");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $contatos=array(
                'id'=>$row['id'],
                'nome'=>$row['nome'],
                'telefone'=>$row['telefone']
            );
            $con->disconnect(); 
            return $contatos;
        }else return null;      
    }
```

Em relação a entrega da informação desejada ambos funcionaram, embora um eu usei uma lib pra ter uma documentação e ser algo mais formal e a outra não. Pode parecer que a minha pergunta é a resposta dela mesmo, porém ai que está a minha dúvida, essas duas formas acima são Webservices? Se não, como classificaria a primeira forma? Posso melhorar a questão se parecer ampla ou vaga demais. (Lembrando que os trechos dos códigos colados aqui são apenas para ilustrar o uso da biblioteca, ainda há as funções, os parses para as responses etc.

Comment: `conceitualmente posso criar um Webservice sem nenhuma Lib?` Conceitualmente, as Libs são webservices "padrão", criados sem nenhuma lib, pra você não ter que criar a sua :)

Comment: show de bola Ricardo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grosso modo, ambos podem ser considerados webservices sim.

O que muda entre eles é o padrão a ser utilizado.

No primeiro caso não existe padrão nenhum, só uma mensagem de confirmação e nada mais. O tratamento de erros não é intuitivo, entre outras coisas.

Já o segundo caso você está utilizando um padrão chamado SOAP. Esse padrão utiliza um formato específico de XML para definir o tipo de requisição esperada e qual a resposta deve ser retornada, de acordo com a implementação do seu sistema. O que muda é que o tratamento de erros, o formato das respostas seguem uma especificação padrão.

Como você irá implementar isso que é o ponto. Você pode tentar criar um webservice para comunicação entre sistemas SOAP sem nenhuma lib, mas não será muito produtivo como utilizar uma lib pronta. Seguir toda uma especificação não é algo trivial.

Ao fornecer um webservice, pense não na sua implementação, mas sim em como a pessoa que vai consumir irá trabalhar. Ao usar um padrão já conhecido, a pessoa que for consumir o serviço irá se focar no que ela precisa e não em ficar decifrando sua API mágica.

O que você prefere como usuário, consumir o serviço do exemplo 1 ou o serviço do exemplo 2?

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, com certeza o exemplo 2 porque possuiria uma documentação e um padrão mais consistente para seguir. Muito obrigado, brother!